# How to split a column of a variable number of concatenated tags into one column per tag?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

Consider the following data:

```
library(tibble)

key <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
tags <- c("A,B", "B", "A,E", "C,D", "")
data <- tibble(key, tags)
```

Here, `key` could mean book title and `tags` could be genres, or `key` could be an email sender and `tags` could mean recipients. Essential is that the column `tags` can have a variable (possibly zero) number of different substrings.

For splitting a fixed number of concatenated tags (e.g. like a data) I can use `tidyr::spread`, and I can use string splitting to separate the `tags` column itself, but how to combine the two?

I would like the transformed data to look like this:

```
key  A     B     C     D     E
a    TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
b    FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
c    TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
d    FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
e    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I can see it's possible to do this in several steps by splitting `tags`, determining the unique substrings and loop over each of them and test if `tags` for each row contains the string. But I'd prefer to do this **in a pipeline using the tidyverse**.

**Question**: how can I split the variable number of concatened tags into one column per tag?

Comment: However, to get close to your desired output, you can try `t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(tags,","),key))))`. Still don't get the `tibble` part and why all those loaded packages.

Comment: Uh, plus one for the `stack()` function.

Comment: @nicola some prefer to stick with tidyverse packages for data cleaning.

Comment: @zx8754 That's doesn't explain at all the presence of all those packages. Just because you like it, it's not enough (IMO) to include them in the question. They are not needed nor to build the input (actually, their use as suggested by the OP leads to an error)  nor necessary to produce the output. Is OP mentioning them because they *require* a solution that exploits them? Or there is another reason?

Comment: @nicola error was caused by typo, and from loaded libraries and tags, I assumed they want to have solution using those packages.

Comment: Also `table(data.table::data.table(key, tags)[, strsplit(tags, ",", fixed = TRUE), by = factor(key)]) == 1` perhaps

Comment: @nicola tnx for spotting the key/keys typo (I had keys everywhere and forgot to replace one instance to key). Yes, my preference was to use the tidyverse, will update to remove the unused packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `separate_rows` function from *tidyr* may help you get where you want.  This splits the strings within `tags` into separate rows instead of separate columns, which sets you up to use `spread`.

To get the `TRUE`/`FALSE` result I created a new column of all `TRUE` to use as the value column, and then filled the missing with `FALSE` in `spread`.  In the end,`spread` kept the blank cell as a column name, which I removed via `select`.  There may be a better way to do this (maybe convert to NA?).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
    separate_rows(tags) %>%
    mutate(tagslog = TRUE) %>%
    spread(tags, tagslog, fill = FALSE) %>%
    select(-one_of(""))

    key     A     B     C     D     E
* <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2     b FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3     c  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4     d FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5     e FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You can almost get where you want with just `separate_rows` and `table`, but I still had that extra blank column that would need to be removed.

```
data %>%
    separate_rows(tags) %>%
    with(., table(key, tags) == 1)

   tags
key           A     B     C     D     E
  a FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  b FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  c FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  d FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  e  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a base R alternative approach:

```
# get unique values in tags
x <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$tags, ",", fixed=TRUE)))
# check for existence in the tags column
res <- sapply(paste0("(^|.*,)", x, "(,.*|$)"), grepl, df$tags)
# add sensible dimension names
dimnames(res) <- list(df$key, x)
```

The resulting matrix looks like this:

```
res
#      A     B     E     C     D
#a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#b FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#c  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#d FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#e FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

A third base R method is

```
# get named list splitting by commas
myList <- setNames(strsplit(tags, split=",", fixed=TRUE), key)
# get unique elements from list
colTemp <- sort(unique(unlist(myList)))
# check each list element for the unique elements, return matrix
myMat <- t(sapply(myList, function(i) colTemp %in% i))
# add column names
colnames(myMat) <- colTemp
```

which returns

```
myMat
      A     B     C     D     E
a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
b FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
c  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
d FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
e FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

From docendo discimus approach, using different way of paste function

```
xx <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(data$tags,","))))

data1 <- sapply(paste(xx), grepl, data$tags)

data <- cbind(data[,1],data1)

  key     A     B     C     D     E
1   a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2   b FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3   c  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4   d FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5   e FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: @docendo discimus Copied your way of approach but changed some syntax using base R,

Comment: There's no reason to use `paste` if your're not actually pasting anything together. The reason I use it is to avoid errors due to fuzzy (regex) matching. This doesn't happen in the example but could easily happen in real world data. For example regex matching `A` in `ABC` would return TRUE

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for your advice i'll implement your approach